# Screen brightness (neither fn button or system settings/ brightness and lock do not work)

Tags: 14.04, brightness

I can't change the brightness with fn button or through System settings/ brightness & lock.What should i do? 
my laptop model is Dell Intel® Core™ i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4 (64-bit)
and for graphics: GeForce 920M/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: May be you changed the values so little that you can not see their effect?

Comment: By fn buttons, I assume you have a laptop.  These problems can be very model-specific so you should add which laptop you are having trouble with.

Comment: If i try to change it trough  brightness and lock with the cursor the brightness does not change no mater if the indicator is on the left or the right corner.
So thats why i believe that its is not a laptop model problem.
but I am not that experienced on a pc, so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Linux Mint XFCE User, and I use `xfpm-power-backlight-helper` to setting the brightness. Maybe this is help you, at least for reference, because it depend on Desktop variant. Different desktop, different tool.

To use this tool via command-line :

```
$ pkexec --user root xfpm-power-backlight-helper --set-brightness 20
```

or you can install `xbacklight` and here is how to use it

```
$ xbacklight -set 20
```

Here the [link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xbacklight) for further info about `xbacklight`